# How do you add extra data to a document in firestore in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

This is how I add data to my Firestore, hopefully it gives you an idea of how my database looks like:

```
val postMap = hashMapOf(
    "date" to currentDate,
    "publisher" to userID,
    "postImage" to myUrl,
    "caption" to binding.etCaption.text.toString().lowercase(),
    "rent" to binding.etHousePrice.text.toString().lowercase(),
    "location" to binding.etHouseLocation.text.toString().lowercase(),
    "rooms" to binding.etNumberOfRooms.text.toString().lowercase(),
    "description" to binding.etPostDescription.text.toString().lowercase()
)
```

I want to add another piece of data as follows but later on

```
val data = hashMapOf("post_id" to id)
```

How do I achieve that without overwriting the existing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the following data later, to an existing document, please use the following lines of code:

```
val data = hashMapOf("post_id" to id)
val db = Firebase.firestore
val postsRef = db.collection("posts")
val postIdRef = postsRef.document(postId)
postIdRef.update(data)
```

More details are below:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

As the docs states, you can also attach a failure lister, to always see if something goes wrong.

Comment: That is all for now. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

```
private var userMap: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap() 
userMap["post_id"] = id
val collection = Firebase.firestore.collection("posts")
        collection.document(postId)
            .update(userMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                //succes update message
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                //failure update message
            }
```